# tf.data.dataset.from_tensor_slices for RNN model

Tags: tf.data.dataset

I have an image dataset including RGB images: img1.png, img2.png ... img250.png. I have extracted 100 small patches with size `[64,64,3]` from each image. So, I have now dataset like **img1_1.png, img1_2.png ...img1_100.png, img2_1.png, img2_2.png, ... img2_100.png, img3_1, .....**

I want to create a data generator with `tf.data.dataset.from_tensor_slices` to pass all patches of each image to an RNN model. So, I wanna the generator creates output like this : `[batch_size, 100, 64, 64, 3]`

How can I do that?

250: is the number of images,
100: is the number of patches that were extracted from each image,
64,64,3: the size of each patch

For each iteration, for example, I want to select for example 32 of the 250 images randomly, and put all 100 patches of them together and create the following format `(32, 100, 64, 64, 3)`

Because of the memory usage, I cannot load all data to a variable. I just have the 25000 patches with name **img1_1.png, img1_2.png ...img1_100.png, img2_1.png, img2_2.png, ... img2_100.png, img3_1, ..... img250_1.png, img250_2.png ...img250_100.png.**

I think its better to use format

```
tf.data.dataset.from_tensor_slices((patch_files,labels)), but I don't know how.
```

It is also important to note that the size of the label vector is (250,1). If the batch size is 32, the generator should output label batches with size (32,1)